# GCC 9.2.0 лучше чем 10.3.0?

Tags: c, gcc, g++

Рассмотрим простую программу *argc.c* которая выводит количество аргументов

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    return 0;
}
```

С помощью gcc версии 9.0.2 переведем текст в ассемблер

gcc -Ofast -S argc.c -o argc.s

```
    .data
LC0:
    .ascii "%d\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    call    _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Если взять gcc версии 10.3.0 то текст на ассемблере выглядит так

```
.data
LC0:
    .ascii "%d\12\0"
    .text
_printf:
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $24, %esp
    leal    36(%esp), %ebx
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    *__imp____acrt_iob_func
    movl    %ebx, 8(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    ___mingw_vfprintf
    addl    $24, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    ret
    .globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    call    _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Заметно что при вызове printf программа делает переход на метку printf: и выполняет подготовительные работы.Отображением на экране теперь занимается функция vfprintf. Чем обусловлено такое не оптимизированное поведение компилятора? Чем плоха функция printf в версии 10.3.0 ?

Comment: Отключи отладку, и взгляни на код... А ещё лучше, поставь стандарт не gnu.

Comment: Выбирайте версию компилятора в зависимости от версии ОС. Я скомпилировал на ubuntu 21.10(GCC 11) и не смог запустить на ubuntu 20.04(GCC 9). Пришлось переносить код и компилировать там.

Comment: @Olegator36 динамическая линковка это вообще другое.

Comment: что значит лучше???

Answer (score 2):

Похоже printf заменили на инлайн и компилятор полностью перенес её в ассемблер.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по порядку:\

1. Что значит лучше?
2. eri правильно указал, printf заменили на инлайн, скорее всего это действительно так(по крайней мере звучит логично)
3. укажите параметр `O` цифрой, как написано в [доке](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gnat_ugn/Optimization-Levels.html#Optimization-Levels), сравните на разных уровнях оптимизации. Вполне вероятно, что с этим тоже может быть связано.
4. Даже если вы проверили все вышеперечисленные пункты и 10 версия работает так же, то это вообще не значит что она хуже, а 9 лучше. Но и обратного тоже не значит. Это просто значит, что он работает по другому. То, что в ассемблерном коде больше команд, ни о чём не говорит, даже с точки зрения скорости выполнения(а я так понял, вы обращаете внимание именно на это).
5. Данная особенность вообще никак не повлияет на скорость работы программы на современных машинах

Comment: где-то читал новый компилятор может заменять функции на инлайны когда ему вздумается.